# r retain rows only if non missing in specific column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My dataframe has columns and rows like this

```
   Id    Date    Col1    Col2    Col3    X1
   1     1/1/22  NA      1       0       
   1     1/1/22  0       0       1       6
   2     5/7/21  0       1       0       
   2     5/7/21  0       2       0
```

I like to drop rows where the duplicate row (same Id, same date) where values for column X1 is missing or empty. If both the rows are missing X1 for that ID and date then dont drop. Only when one is missing and other is not missing then drop the missing row.

Expected output

```
  Id    Date    Col1    Col2    Col3    X1
   1     1/1/22  0       0       1       6
   2     5/7/21  0       1       0       
   2     5/7/21  0       2       0
```

I tried this

```
  library(tidyr)
  df %>%
  group_by(Id, Date) %>%
  drop_na(X1)
```

This drops all rows with NA or missing and I am just left with one row, which is not what I want. Any suggestions much apricated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a condition in `filter` to return `all` the rows if there are only missing values in 'X1' or just remove the missing rows

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Id, Date) %>% 
   filter(if(all(is.na(X1))) TRUE else complete.cases(X1)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
     Id Date    Col1  Col2  Col3    X1
  <int> <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1 1/1/22     0     0     1     6
2     2 5/7/21     0     1     0    NA
3     2 5/7/21     0     2     0    NA
```

---

Or without the `if/else`, use `|` with `&` condition

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Id, Date) %>%
  filter(any(complete.cases(X1)) & complete.cases(X1) | 
       all(is.na(X1))) %>% 
  ungroup
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Date = c("1/1/22", "1/1/22", 
"5/7/21", "5/7/21"), Col1 = c(NA, 0L, 0L, 0L), Col2 = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 2L), Col3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X1 = c(NA, 6L, NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```